# DataTable Highcharts Pie chart to show number of occurrences of a value in a cloumn

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts, datatables

I was reading this stackoverflow post

[PIE CHART - Data Visualization With DataTables and Highcharts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52696493/pie-chart-data-visualization-with-datatables-and-highcharts)

I'm new to Highcharts. I was trying to re-use the javascript code for my purposes but to no avail so far.

I don't need the column charts, just the pie chart. But Im looking to do something different.

For my purpose, I actually have a column for STATUS that says fail success or aborted. I want the pie chart to show the number of each. So if I search for today's date, I may see 10 success, 2 fail and 1 aborted. I want the Pie chart to show me that.

thanks

Comment: Hi @Roger McCarrick, Could you reproduce your current stage in a live example, starting from here: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/pbgc1j04/

Comment: Thanks, I had a typo and I had another JS causing 2 initializations of the table